# "MySQL server has gone away" error after few hours of inactivity

Tags: mysql, django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a Django app running on Apache with wsgi module.
After few hours of inactivity I get that error and I have to restart the Apache.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say what exactly is your problem is with so less details. Did you check the [MySQL reference regarding this error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)? Did you work through it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message mean that the database server has closed the connection to you. I guess this is caused because the connection is idle.

I believe you can get this fixed by adjusting the wait_timeout inside the configuration file of your mysql database server. The file is most commonly named "my.cnf".

This, however, is not considered as a good practice. I would like to suggest you to optimize the application you are writing to open the connection to mysql on demand - there's no point to keep it open if you are not actively using it for a long time.

If you need a quick fix, use the mysql_ping() function to check whether the connection is still alive and re-open if necessary.